# Is there a way to bypass root object during deserialization?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I get a JSON response like this :

```
{
    "xpubaddressONE":{"final_balance":123,"n_tx":0,"total_received":0},
    "xpubaddressTWO":{"final_balance":25221,"n_tx":0,"total_received":0},
    "xpubaddressTHREE":{"final_balance":1123,"n_tx":0,"total_received":0}
}
```

I want to deserialize it into C# object. I need to build classes like this :

```
public class xpubaddressONE
{
    public int final_balance { get; set; }
    public int n_tx { get; set; }
    public int total_received { get; set; }
}

public class xpubaddressTHREE
{
    public int final_balance { get; set; }
    public int n_tx { get; set; }
    public int total_received { get; set; }
}

public class xpubaddressTWO
{
    public int final_balance { get; set; }
    public int n_tx { get; set; }
    public int total_received { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public xpubaddressONE one { get; set; }
    public xpubaddressTWO two { get; set; }
    public xpubaddressTHREE three { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to remove additional classes(xpubaddressONE,xpubaddressTWO,xpubaddressTHREE) and access objects like this :

> RootObject.final_balance

Comment: *Why* do you have `xpubaddressONE`, etc? Why not just have a single `xpubaddress`?

Comment: The problem is that `RootObject.final_balance` isn't unique, because you have 3 different final balances. It seems like this should really be an array of `xpubaddress` objects

Comment: @MindSwipe or a dictionary, i.e. `Dictionary<string, xpubaddress>` which would have *keys* `"xpubaddressONE"`, `"xpubaddressTWO"` and `"xpubaddressTHREE"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try deserializing a `Dictionary<string, xpubaddress>`, where `xpubaddress` is:

```cs
public class xpubaddress
{
    public int final_balance { get; set; }
    public int n_tx { get; set; }
    public int total_received { get; set; }
}
```

This should then give you a dictionary with 3 *keys* that you can inspect with `foreach`, `TryGetValue`, etc.

---

Alternatively, stick with your root type, but share the inner type:

```cs
public class xpubaddress
{
    public int final_balance { get; set; }
    public int n_tx { get; set; }
    public int total_received { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public xpubaddress xpubaddressONE{ get; set; }
    public xpubaddress xpubaddressTWO{ get; set; }
    public xpubaddress xpubaddressTHREE { get; set; }
}
```

You may also find it easier to leave the property names as idiomatic .NET names, and use `[JsonProperty]` or `[DataMember]` to rename them, i.e.

```cs
[JsonProperty("final_balance")]
public int FinalBalance { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce the single `xpubaddress` class, like

```cs
public class xpubaddress
{
    public int final_balance { get; set; }
    public int n_tx { get; set; }
    public int total_received { get; set; }
}
```

and then deserialize it into `IDictionary<string, xpubaddress>` for example, add access objects using the `xpubaddressONE`, `xpubaddressTWO`, etc., keys

```cs
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, xpubaddress>>(json);
var balance = result?["xpubaddressONE"]?.final_balance ?? 0;
```